# Child nodes not go out of the parent div

Tags: javascript, html, jsplumb

I have this `div`:

```
<div id="composition_area" style="width: 700px; height: 600px; float:left; border: solid 2px">
            <div id="a" class="a window" style="width: 80px; height: 80px; border: solid 1px" contenteditable="true">foo</div>
</div>
```

and  inside of this with `id="composition_area"` I add nodes with the `jsplumb`. In this example I have a node with `id="a"`. All the nodes are draggable and the user can move the divs anywhere he wants. But I want **not** to go out of the parent div. How can I do that?

Comment: isn't that a setting on the plugin that is making the inner divs draggable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the doc http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/home#dragging

> A common request is for the ability to contain the area within which
>   an element may be dragged. For jQuery this is as simple as providing a
>   containment parameter:
>
> jsPlumb.draggable($("someSelector"), {   containment:"parent" });

try this :

```
jsPlumb.draggable($("#composition_area"), {
  containment:"parent"
});
```