# jsPlumb connecting two sub-divs

Tags: jsplumb

I want to connect two containers with jsPlumb. Every container should have an structure with several sub-div´s. You can see it at fiddle [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/2AFGW/4/)

An container looks like this:

```
    <div class="window" style="left: 20px" id="container0">
            <div class="connect" id="c0_I0">In0</div>
            <div class="connect" id="c0_I1">In1</div>
            <div class="connect" id="c0_O0">Out0</div>
    </div>
```

And every .connect-element get an anchor from jsPlumb by this code:

```
    jsPlumb.addEndpoint(
       $('#c1_I0'),
       anEndpointDestination
    );
```

The container is styled by this css:

```
background-color: #AADD88;
border-top: 1px solid #555555;
color: black;
position: absolute;
```

My problem: If I´ll connect container0-Out0 with container1-In1 the drawn line connects conatiner0-Out0 with container0-In1. I tried several things because it should be possible if I understand the doc but I failed.

[This doesn´t help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792233/child-nodes-not-go-out-of-the-parent-div)

[This I din´t understand?!](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/home#dragging)

What is the problem? I need this container conept and normaly I want to extend it to from

```
<div class="window">
   <div class="Inputs"> <-- This level is actual not implemented, but it would be nice to have for the UI
      <div id="In1"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

---

UPDATE:

After three days of reading, searching and so on...I decided to ask my question...and some times it the answer is to ask the question:

All I had to do was setting the default value for container...and I did this several times but for the wrong class.

```
jsPlumb.Defaults.Container = $("body");
```